# Using mapped types to return object of return types of functions

Tags: typescript

I have a function that will take an object as a parameter and return a new object. The object parameter will be an object of functions that return arbitrary types and the return type of my function will be an object of the same keys as the object parameter but the values will be the return types of the keys' respective functions from the object parameter.

Now the catch is, the functions from the object parameter can potentially throw errors and I don't want to break execution in the middle of the process but instead collect all the keys that failed and then throw my own custom error.

This is what I have so far:

```
type ObjectParamFn =  <T>(...arbitrary: any[]) => T | never;
type ObjectParam = { [key: string]: ObjectParamFn };
type MyMethodReturnType<T extends ObjectParam> = {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>;
}

function myMethod<T extends ObjectParam>(
    param: T
): MyMethodReturnType<T> | never {
    const returnValue = {} as MyMethodReturnType<T>;
    const errors = [];
    for (let propName in param) {
        if (param.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            try {
                const value = param[propName](/* arbitrary */);
                returnValue[propName] = value; // TS ERROR HERE: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T[Extract<keyof T, string>]>'.
            } catch (err) {
                errors.push(propName);
            }
        }
    }

    if (errors.length) {
        throw new Error('foo');
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

I marked where the TS Error I receive is, but to break it out into it's own line:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T[Extract<keyof T, string>]>'.`

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but can't quite get over that last hump. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes type assertions are necessary. This is one of those times

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by removing the generic-ness of `ObjectParamFn` since in my codebase I actually know the class of return types so I defined that as a union and worked from there.

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null;
type ObjectParamFn = (...arbitrary: any[]) => Primitive | never;
type ObjectParam = { [key: string]: ObjectParamFn };
type MyMethodReturnType<T extends ObjectParam> = {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>;
}

function myMethod<T extends ObjectParam>(
    param: T
): MyMethodReturnType<T> | never {
    let returnValue = {} as { [key: string]: any };
    const errors = [];
    for (let propName in param) {
        if (param.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            try {
                returnValue[propName] = param[propName]();
            } catch (err) {
                errors.push(propName);
            }
        }
    }

    if (errors.length) {
        throw new Error('foo');
    }

    return returnValue as MyReturnType<T>;
}
```